# Отключить алерты с исключениями opencart

Tags: javascript, php, исключения, opencart, opencart3.x

Имеется уже готовый магазин на opencart 3.

Проблема заключается в том, что иногда в карточке товара, при добавлении товара в корзину, выскакивают алерты такого вида http://prntscr.com/ng3z67 .

На работоспособность они никак не влияют и все работает правильно.

Вторая проблема в том, что если у товара есть обязательные опции и они не указаны то после нажатия кнопки "добавить в корзину" страница перезагружается.

В common.js я закомментировал следующее:

В функции добавления:

```
if (json['redirect']) {
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }
```

В функциях добавления, обновления и удаления:

```
alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
```

Как полностью отключить вывод ошибок в алертах **на всём сайте при любых непонятных ситуациях** и убрать перезагрузку страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из личного опыта работы с **opencart**: я делал поиск по проекту и все **alert()** переводил в **console.log() / console.dir()**. Так вы не теряете ошибки, дебажить проще. Конечно, делать это стоит с полным пониманием происходящего.